# Manifest.json file not working properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, manifest

i have a chrome extension for creating a button in Gmail webpage.

the button was created successfully in  on that page.but after refreshing that page,the button was not created.it gives aa class undefined.

after clearing the cache and cookies,it works.but not all time,sometimes only.

my manifest.json file code here:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "E-mail Security",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a Email security ",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [ "notifications", "contentSettings", "cookies", "tabs", "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {     

    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["ngContent.js","jquery.js"]

    }
]

}
```

why,that above problem was occured.whether i miss something in manifest.json file?

note:i am using chrome browser.

Comment: Gmail loads dynamically, so perhaps the page element to which you wanted to attach your button sometimes does not yet exist when your content script runs. You'd need to find some event that triggers on the page that indicates when the page is ready to be altered by your script.

Answer (score 1):

Create the button when the page loads. Then perhaps define an event for MutationObserver. Every time the button disappears, your code should get triggered to create it once again. Then apply whatever other rules/actions you want to for that button.